# How can you make a lightbox consume the entire page and appear seamless to the user?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

We would like to create a full page lightbox appear when the page loads. Currently we can only get that to happen after it displays some of the elements behind the lightbox (e.g. the clients logo, navigation, etc).

- I want it to be seamless to the user and just look like a landing
  page. Just looking for ideas as I know the head content loads before
  body content.
- The javascript is an analytics code that we provide to clients and it
  has to go in the body of the page, and we do not have access to the
  head section of their website.
- They will be coming from an ad - so they will be expecting the
  content and it will look like a website. It's merely an easier way to
  get a landing page setup on a clients website without them having to 
  use FTPs, create a blank page, add code, etc.

So I either need a way to load the javascript in the body before the javascript in the head OR a way to block out all of the content in the background of the page as the lightbox loads.

Comment: Do it without javascript, otherwise you will always have said flash. If that isn't an option, then what you are asking isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I have had before with other libraries. What I narrowed it down to was the event I was checking to fire off the lightbox script. Some lightbox scripts will wait for the `window` object to load before allowing you to initiate the lightbox, and others will not. You need the latter. Also the event you hook into shouldn't be the `window` loading but rather the DOM being ready. In jQuery it would be:

```
jQuery(documument).ready(function(){ 
    //some code 
});
```

In vanilla JS it would be:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // some code
});
```

This will wait for all DOM elements to load, but will fire before any elements have rendered. This should be a good spot to fire off your lightbox since all elements needed will be in the DOM but not on the page. That should put your lightbox in the DOM when the page is rendered and you wont get the [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

**Another Option**

Another decent route you could take could be adding the lightbox to the page in the HTML and setting a cookie to hide the lightbox. New users will get the lightbox instantly and returning users aren't bothered with another popup. You see this on a lot of healthcare and government sites.